# What is mitochondrial run length?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, mitochondria

I am reading the following journal [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29190615/) and I have come across the following statement:

> Overexpression of GSK-3β significantly increases motile mitochondria
> in a Tau protein-dependent manner. However, GSK-3β does not alter
> mitochondrial velocity or mitochondrial run length.

I understand what mitochondrial velocity is but I am not sure what exactly is meant by mitochondrial run length. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run length means how far the mitochondria move, each time they move.

The article this references is:

"GSK3β Is Involved in the Relief of Mitochondria Pausing in a Tau-Dependent Manner".

This article has a figure showing the distances in micrometers, although I have trouble working out interpreting the error bars on the graph to see if the distances ("run length") are really different.